# Redux observable with axios in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-observable

Good Day,

im trying to update my database through the epic and subsequently dispatching the response back to update the store. 
However, while the action eventually dispatches to my store, the payload is undefined. I understand it is some problem with updateArticle not fetching fast enough. How do i allow it to wait for updateArticle to return the response before dispatching to the store?

My epic:

```
  action$.pipe(
flowing left-to-right, calling each function with the output of the last one.
    filter(action => action.type === "ADD_ARTICLE_EPIC"), 
    switchMap(
      action =>
        from(updateArticle(action.payload)).pipe(
          map(action => {
            console.log(action);
            return { type: "ADD_ARTICLE", payload: action.payload };
          })
        )
      // return { type: "ADD_ARTICLE", payload: action.payload };
    )
  );
```

My axios:

```
export const updateArticle = async article => {
  const response = await axios.post(`/articles/updateArticle`, article);
  return response.data;
};
```

Comment: You might need to add Redux-Thunk in order to make Redux asynchronous. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: correct if im wrong but instead of thunks, i can actually manage async through redux oberservables? https://sandstorm.de/de/blog/post/async-redux-middleware-comparison.html

Comment: I haven't dove into observables but I know I can accomplish what you are trying to do via thunks :). It's super easy, the syntax is exactly what Maximilliano posted

Comment: indeed. But im currently trying to learn observables so yea. thanks anw!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for doing that using redux and redux-thunk.

API.conversation.sendMessage is doing an axios post request behind the scenes.

```
  export const sendNewMessage = message => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const { data } = await API.conversation.sendNewMessage(message);
      dispatch({
        type: SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_OK,
        payload: data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_ERROR,
        payload: error,
      });
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: correct if im wrong but instead of thunks, i can actually manage async through redux oberservables? https://sandstorm.de/de/blog/post/async-redux-middleware-comparison.html